# Update entry widget value that has StringVar based on another StringVar value inside new window

Tags: python, tkinter

so like the title says i want to update one StringVar variable based on value from another StringVar variable in tkinter that are in widow separate from the initial one as you will see. I know the code will be messy but bear with it. Initially we create couple of buttons that generate sql scripts that i hardcoded. When i press a button a new window opens where i enter information about a database name, table name, column name... When i enter correct table name in entry2 widget it prints correct columns from the database in function show_columns in string variable str. Let's assume the database name is DATABASE. What i want is to put content of str variable into column variable that's binded to entry3 widget. How do i do that?

```
def show_columns(table):
    query = f"select * from [DATABASE].[dbo].[{table}] where 1=0"
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    str = ''
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
        column_names = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
        for column in column_names: str += f"[{column}],"
        print(str)
    except:
        print('Error!')



def open_window(text, button):
    # Create a new window
    new_window = Toplevel()

    # Set the window title and size
    new_window.title(text)
    new_window.geometry("600x460")
    new_window.config(bg="light gray")
    new_window.resizable(False, False)

    database = StringVar()
    table = StringVar()
    column = StringVar()


    # Create some text fields
    label1 = Label(new_window, text="Database name:").grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5)
    entry1 = Entry(new_window, textvariable=database).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

    label2 = Label(new_window, text="Table name:").grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5)
    entry2 = Entry(new_window, textvariable=table).grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

    label3 = Label(new_window, text="Column name:").grid(row=2, column=0, pady=5)
    entry3 = Entry(new_window, textvariable=column).grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    
    table.trace_add('write', lambda name, index, mode, sv=table: show_columns(sv.get()))




window = Tk()

#code for connecting to database


#Set the window title, size and oclor
window.title('SQL script generator')
window.geometry("800x600")
window.config(bg="gray")
window.resizable(False, False)

command_names = ['Delete duplicates while keeping the original', 
                 'Delete duplicates without keeping the original',
                 'Retrive all data from table',
                 'Check for duplicates',
                 'Delete table',
                 'Copy data from one table to another',
                 'Update values',
                 'Add new column to exisitng table']


canvas = Canvas(window)
canvas.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)


# Create two frames
search_frame = Frame(canvas)
search_frame.pack(side='top')
buttons_frame = Frame(canvas)
buttons_frame.pack(side='bottom')
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=buttons_frame, anchor='nw')


i = 0
for i, text in enumerate(command_names):
    Button(buttons_frame, text=command_names[i], width=40, height=2, command=lambda text = text, index = i: open_window(text, index)).grid(row=i+1, column=0, pady=5, padx=5)
    i += 1


buttons_frame.update_idletasks()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Pass `column` as an argument to `show_columns()`, then you can update it inside the function.

Comment: Already tried that and it didn't work. Passed the column to show_columns() and in that function i did column.set(str), but unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: That's interesting, I was able to do this successfully both as described by @acw1668 and as an instance variable!

Comment: If you use `column` as the argument name of `show_columns()`, then it won't work because it is override by the local variable `column` defined in the for loop inside the function.  It works when using another name as the argument.

Comment: If you use the same variable in both places, the widgets will automatically update whenever the value changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty of translating your code into an OOP approach. In my opinion, this is easier to read, and you can use instance variables to exchange values between methods within a class without passing them directly. For example, you could introduce the variables `database`, `table` and `column` within `__init__` with the prefix `self` and then within `show_columns` simply set the variable with `self.column.set(str)`.

**Attention**, in my code I have replaced `str` with `output`, as `str` is already used in the standard (type). This version is shown in the method `show_columns_v2`.

You can also pass `entry3` into the `show_columns` method and then insert the result into the `entry` using the `insert` method. Note here that you have assigned the variable `entry3` with the return value of the `grid` method, not with the `entry`. In my code I fixed this by first creating `entry3` and then applying the `grid` method to it.

**Note**: Since I don't have your database, I have set the variable or inserted the value into the `entry` in the `except` bracket.

Here is my code:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel, Label, Entry, Canvas, Frame, Button, StringVar


class GUI(Tk):
    def __init__(self):  # create own GUI class which inherits from Tk → window is now self
        super().__init__()
        # Set the window title, size and oclor
        self.title('SQL script generator')
        self.geometry("800x600")
        self.config(bg="gray")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        command_names = ['Delete duplicates while keeping the original',
                         'Delete duplicates without keeping the original',
                         'Retrive all data from table',
                         'Check for duplicates',
                         'Delete table',
                         'Copy data from one table to another',
                         'Update values',
                         'Add new column to exisitng table']

        canvas = Canvas(self)
        canvas.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)

        # Create two frames
        search_frame = Frame(canvas)
        search_frame.pack(side='top')
        buttons_frame = Frame(canvas)
        buttons_frame.pack(side='bottom')
        canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=buttons_frame, anchor='nw')

        # Create instance variables
        self.database = StringVar(self, value='')
        self.table = StringVar(self, value='')
        self.column = StringVar(self, value='')

        # Create Buttons with loop
        for i, text in enumerate(command_names):
            Button(buttons_frame, text=command_names[i], width=40, height=2,
                   command=lambda: self.open_window(text)).grid(row=i + 1, column=0, pady=5, padx=5)

    def open_window(self, text):
        # Create a new window
        new_window = Toplevel()

        # Set the window title and size
        new_window.title(text)
        new_window.geometry("600x460")
        new_window.config(bg="light gray")
        new_window.resizable(False, False)

        # Create some text fields
        Label(new_window, text="Database name:").grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5)
        entry1 = Entry(new_window, textvariable=self.database)
        entry1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        Label(new_window, text="Table name:").grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5)
        entry2 = Entry(new_window, textvariable=self.table)
        entry2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        Label(new_window, text="Column name:").grid(row=2, column=0, pady=5)
        entry3 = Entry(new_window, textvariable=self.column)
        entry3.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        #self.table.trace_add('write', lambda name, index, mode, entry=entry3: self.show_columns(sv.get(), entry))
        # version to set by changing self.column directly
        self.table.trace_add('write', lambda name, index, mode: self.show_columns_v2())

    # version without instance vaiable by inserting to entry directly
    def show_columns(self, entry3):
        table = self.table.get()
        query = f"select * from [DATABASE].[dbo].[{table}] where 1=0"
        output = ''
        try:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(query)
            column_names = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
            for column in column_names:
                output += f"[{column}],"
            print(output)
        except:
            print(f'Error for Table {table}!')
            # test to set entry
            output = 'test'
            entry3.insert(0, output)

    # version 2 setting StringVar directly
    def show_columns_v2(self):
        table = self.table.get()
        query = f"select * from [DATABASE].[dbo].[{table}] where 1=0"
        output = ''
        try:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(query)
            column_names = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
            for column in column_names:
                output += f"[{column}],"
            print(output)
        except:
            print(f'Error for Table {table}!')
            # test to set entry
            output = 'test'
            self.column.set(output)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui = GUI()
    gui.mainloop()
```

**By the way**: maybe you should not trigger the `show_columns` method via `table.trace_add('write'...`, unless you copy the table name into this field. Because if you type the name, the function is triggered with every letter. Instead, you can also insert a button such as 'Search columns', which then triggers the `show_columns` method.

Comment: Great, this solved it. Can't believe i did't notice entry was being tied to grid and that's why that approach didn't work for me. Thank you so much for the help.